# Nginx serving .PHP as a download only when .php is added with arguments

Tags: nginx, security, php-fpm

Here is my current nginx config:

```
server {
server_name mydomain.example;
access_log /srv/www/mydomain.example/logs/access.log;
error_log /srv/www/mydomain.example/logs/error.log;
root /srv/www/mydomain.example/public_html;
error_page 404 /404;

location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)\.(php|html)$) { return 302 $1$is_args$args; }
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm @php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location @php {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri.php $uri/index.php =404;
}

location /support {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 break;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm @php;
}

location /blog {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 break;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm @php;
}

}
```

So basically I have a huge security issue which needs to be fixed asap. When I go to "mydomain.example/filename?arg=7887" everything works fine. But when a client attempts to go to "mydomain.example/filename.php?arg=7887" the server decides to serve the file as a download. I need it to strip .php and rewrite it to "mydomain.example/filename?arg=7887". It only seems to happen when there's arguments after the .php, otherwise it'll strip the .php and work fine.

Comment: Don't use separate entry points to your application. Use a front controller.

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry, I'm kind of a noob at this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the `try_files` madness and other questionable approaches. Remove all of your exercises and make it canonical:

`location / {
     index index.html;
     if (!-e $request_filename) {
         rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php;
     }
}`

`location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_cache default;
    break;
}`

Comment: If possible I would like to have extensions removed from my pages (except for /blog and /support directories). Is there a way to solve this without removing the function of my configuration?

Comment: Your request just doesn't make sense.

Comment: How would I remove .php from all pages except for the directories /blog and /support while fixing this security issue? Your solution gives me nginx errors and it isn't what I want to accomplish.

Comment: There's no point in removing `.php` extensions from web links, and this has nothing to do with security. Example above is taken from a production server, furthermore, this is a standard approach. If you are about to accomplish something weird, but still reachable with standard approaches, then you're on your own.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to stick to the standard approach. It just looks nicer without extensions. Thanks anyways.